# How to convert from double vector to integer vector in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, rank

When I run the code shown below, I get the output shown immediately beneath:

```
library(dplyr)

myData <- 
  data.frame(
    Element = c("A","A","B","A","C","C"),
    Group = c(0,0,0,0,1,1)
  )

myDataGroups <- myData %>%
  mutate(origOrder = row_number()) %>%  
  group_by(Element) %>% 
  mutate(ElementCnt = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%  
  mutate(Group = factor(Group, unique(Group))) %>% 
  arrange(Group) %>% 
  mutate(groupCt = cumsum(Group != lag(Group, 1, Group[[1]])) - 1L) %>%  
  group_by(Group) %>%  
  mutate(GroupRank = ElementCnt - groupCt,
         GroupRank = if_else( as.character(Group) == "0", ElementCnt, min(GroupRank))
  )%>%  
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(origOrder)
myDataGroups

Output:

> myDataGroups
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Element Group origOrder ElementCnt groupCt GroupRank
  <chr>   <fct>     <int>      <int>   <int>     <int>
1 A       0             1          1      -1         1
2 A       0             2          2      -1         2
3 B       0             3          1      -1         1
4 A       0             4          3      -1         3
5 C       1             5          1       0         1
6 C       1             6          2       0         1
```

However, when I add a max function to the above changing the line `mutate(GroupRank = ElementCnt - groupCt,...)` to `mutate(GroupRank = ElementCnt - max(0,groupCt),...)` I get an error message *Error: Problem with mutate() column GroupRank.
i GroupRank = if_else(as.character(Group) == "0", ElementCnt, min(GroupRank)).
x false must be an integer vector, not a double vector*. I have tried fiddling with `as.integer(...)` throughout with no luck.

And if I don't insert the above max function but instead change the line `GroupRank = if_else( as.character(Group) == "0", ElementCnt, min(GroupRank))` to `GroupRank = max(1,if_else( as.character(Group) == "0", ElementCnt, min(GroupRank)))` I get these nonsensical GroupRank results:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Element Group origOrder ElementCnt groupCt GroupRank
  <chr>   <fct>     <int>      <int>   <int>     <dbl>
1 A       0             1          1      -1         3
2 A       0             2          2      -1         3
3 B       0             3          1      -1         3
4 A       0             4          3      -1         3
5 C       1             5          1       0         1
6 C       1             6          2       0         1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Change the `0` to `0L` to ensure integer output.

Comment: Thanks Hugh that works. I'll post another question dealing with my max(1...) quirk.

Comment: `if_else` is very picky about data types. Using the base `ifelse()` instead is an easy workaround.

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 I think you might want `pmax()` rather than `max()` - that would explain why you think the behaviour is quirky!